# How to find every palindrome substring in a given string and return an occurence value in under a second

Tags: java

I've been struggling with a problem which is as follows:

> You are given a string of lower-case Latin letters. Let us define a
>   substring's "occurrence value" as the number of the substring
>   occurrences in the string multiplied by the length of the substring.
>   For a given string find the largest occurrence value of palindromic
>   substrings.

My code works perfectly, however, I need to get the solution in under a second for an input of up to 300 000 characters. My code so far is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initiate a scanner
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pal = in.nextLine();
    getAllPalindrome(pal);

}

/**
 * checks if the given string is a palindrome
 * 
 * @param pal
 * @return
 */
public static boolean checkPalindrome(String pal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pal.length() / 2; i++) {
        if (pal.charAt(i) != pal.charAt(pal.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * gets all palindromes
 * 
 * @param pal
 */
public static void getAllPalindrome(String pal) {
    // initiate variables
    ArrayList<String> pals = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;
    // add all palindromes to an arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < pal.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < pal.length(); j++) {
            if (checkPalindrome(pal.substring(i, j + 1))) {
                pals.add(pal.substring(i, j + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    int[] counts = new int[pals.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < pals.size(); i++) {
        int lCount = 0;
        String j = pals.get(i);
        for (int k = 0; k < pals.size(); k++) {
            if (j.equals(pals.get(k))) {
                lCount += 1;

            }
            counts[i] = lCount * pals.get(i).length();
        }

    }

    int hov = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pals.size(); i++) {
        if (counts[i] > hov) {
            hov = counts[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hov);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions for speed improvement:

1. you are creating more String objects than you actually need. Every time you call substring you are creating a new String.
2. you are storing and thus processing scores for more String objects than you need. Instead of an ArrayList you could have a Set... or better yet a Map where the Entry also contains a Score.
3. consider how finding each palindrome centered at a position might be more efficient than finding each palindrome beginning at a position
4. Consider how you might eliminate processing for items which could not possibly exceed the current high score. (Hint: using properties of symmetry, as in "Manacher's algorithm").
5. When your input length is several hundreds of thousands, you can begin to see performance improvement with parallel processing approaches. The java-8 streams provide a simple method of parrallel computation.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to refactor your code a little bit.

1. First of all you have to collect all **unique** palindromes and count how many time each of them occures in the string.
2. Iterate over the map and miltiply palindrome length and it's occurence (i.e. find total length of each unique palindrome).
3. Retrieve maximum.

---

```
public class Palindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println(getMaxOccurrenceValue(scan.nextLine()));
        }

    }

    /** Retrieve maximum occurrence value */
    public static int getMaxOccurrenceValue(String pal) {
        return getAllPalindromes(pal).entrySet().stream()
                                     .map(entry -> entry.getKey().length() * entry.getValue())
                                     .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                                     .max().orElse(0);
    }

    /** Retrieve all unique palindromes for given str with occurrence amount of each palindrome */
    private static Map<String, Integer> getAllPalindromes(String str) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) {
                String sub = str.substring(i, j);

                if (isPalindrome(sub))
                    map.compute(sub, (key, count) -> Optional.ofNullable(count).orElse(0) + 1);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    /** Check is given str palindrome or not */
    private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
            if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```